# How to use StreamWriter.WriteLine method to write unix endofline terminator '\n' in C#?

Tags: c#, newline

`StreamWriter.WriteLine` write endofline terminator automatically, but It seems that the default endofline terminator for `StreamWriter.WriteLine` method is `\r\n`, is it possible to change it to `\n` for unix platform?

I'm running the code on Windows 10, Is it platform-related? Can I use `StreamWriter.WriteLine` to output a textfile with unix endofline terminator `\n` on Windows environment?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("NewLineText.txt", true);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("new line test" + i);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the exact problem is "how to write a textfile on the windows platform using just the unix \n as endofline terminator"? Is _sw.Write("Text\n");_ good enough?

Comment: @Steve No, the exact problem is "Is is possible to use StreamWriter.WriteLine method to write the unix endofline terminator \n on windows platform".

Comment: Have you tried setting `sw.NewLine`?

Comment: `TextWriter` has a `NewLine` property you can use

Comment: By the way, you should probably edit your question to make it clear that you want code running on a Windows machine to output a *nix-style newline (`\n`) as at the moment it reads like you don't realise `Environment.NewLine` will be correct for the platform it runs on (i.e. `\r\n` on Windows and `\n` on other OSes).

Comment: You mean by setting [`StreamWriter.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-6.0#properties)? (No direct link since the property's inherited from `TextWriter`.)

Comment: why not just write \n always? It works on all the platforms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> StreamWriter.WriteLine write endofline terminator automatically, but It seems that the default endofline terminator for StreamWriter.WriteLine method is '\r\n', is it possible to change it to '\n' for unix platform?

It will already use `\n` when running on Unix.

> I'm running the code on Windows 10, Is it platform-related?

Yes.

> Can I use StreamWriter.WriteLine to output a textfile with unix endofline terminator '\n' on Windows environment?

Yes - by changing the `NewLine` property. All you need to do is set the property before you call `WriteLine`:

```cs
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("NewLineText.txt", true);
sw.NewLine = "\n"; // Use Unix line endings
// Other code as before
```

As an aside, I'd also suggest using a `using` statement so that the writer is disposed appropriately - and personally I'd generally use `File.AppendText` or `File.CreateText`. So:

```cs
using var writer = File.AppendText("NewLineText.txt");
writer.NewLine = "\n"; // Use Unix line endings
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    writer.WriteLine($"new line test {i}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think it should be `writer.WriteLine($"new line test {i}");` in the second code.

Comment: @obnews: Yup, fixed.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you use `Write` instead of `WriteLine` or write an extension method.

```cs
public static class UnixStreamWriter
{
   public static void WriteLineUnix(this StreamWriter writer, string value)
   {
       writer.Write(value+"\n");
   }
}
```

then you can call it like,

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("NewLineText.txt", true);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   sw.WriteLineUnix("new line test" + i);
}
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Why not just set the `NewLine` property on the writer instead, which would mean it could be used with existing code that calls `WriteLine`. That feels like a more consistent and reliable approach to me.

Comment: `NewLine` property on windows machine will still emit `\r\n` on windows. I beileve author wants to run this program on Windows, but then use the output file on  `NewLineText.txt` Unix.

Comment: The edited description now clearly states this. So I believe this is a solution.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting *reading* from the `NewLine` property. The point is to *set* the `NewLine` property to `"\n"`, at which point `WriteLine` will write the desired line terminator. In other words, the only change required to the original code is to add `sw.NewLine = "\n";` before the `for` loop.

Comment: That makes sense. I got you wrong initally. You should post that as an answer too.